# How to get a single record from ymail.messages with mid using YQL?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I am using following query to retrieve a single record from the ymail.messages table -

```
select message from ymail.msgcontent where (fid,mids) in (select folder.folderInfo.fid,
mid from ymail.messages where query="Yahoo" and mid="-----" limit 1)
```

but I am not able to get a single record instead of that I am getting bunch of records.

what modifications in above query will get a single record?

Answer (score -1):

Change to:

```
select message
from ymail.msgcontent
where (fid,mids) in (
    select folder.folderInfo.fid, mid
    from ymail.messages
    where query="Yahoo" and mid="-----" | truncate(count=1))
```